# What icons should I create for my website in 2020?

Tags: icons, favicon

I have been making websites for many years now, and have always created a favicon.ico.

But over the years many other "standard" icons have appeared, for mac, for windows, for android, for iphone, etc, etc, etc.

Personally I have always ignored them ... but maybe it is appropriate to put at least some?

- But which ones are worth putting on?
- What size and format?
- How should they be called? (filename, like favicon.ico)
- Where to put it? All in the root?

To have them or not, will it affect the SEO and search engine indexing of a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a technical point of view, a single SVG icon would be a good thing.
I you want you can target each platform individually:

iOS Safari - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Android Chrome -
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Edge and IE 12 -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dn320426(v=vs.85)

Desktop browsers -

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico">
```